# php artisan db:seed [ErrorException] count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new to Laravel, i am seeding into a table called "area" in a database. Please this is an open source project I am learning with. Below is the code that gives the above error. Please don't close my question, I have research anywhere I could for help.

```
   <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Area;
use Carbon\Carbon;
class AreaTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Area::insert([
          ['name' => 'Dhanmondi', 'created_at' => Carbon::now(), 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()], 
        ]);
    }
}
```

I am seeding into the "area" table with the columns: name, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at.
Can I be getting this error because I left the "deleted_at" column null?
thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you sure that it should be a sub array?
I mean "Area::insert([[" and not only one square-bracket? "Area::insert([ ...])" ?

Comment: I did what u suggested but i got the same error.

Comment: Can you please share the trace log of the error?

Comment: Did you has an factory? If so update the code with it and show the model too, pls. Whe may have a problem with execution on the seeder, not the definition.

Comment: $ php artisan db:seed
Seeding: AreaTableSeeder


  [ErrorException]
  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable


@OfirBaruch

Comment: Instead of **insert** try **create**, like : `Area::create([ 'name' => 'Dhanmondi', 'created_at' => Carbon::now(), 'updated_at' => Carbon::now() ]);`

Comment: I would also look inside the Area model for usage of `count()` incase there is some custom logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Remember to mark this answer as the best answer) :)

So I put the solution here so that it's visible to everyone :

Instead of **insert** try **create**, like :

```
Area::create([ 
'name' => 'Dhanmondi', 
'created_at' => Carbon::now(), 
'updated_at' => Carbon::now() 
]);
```